# Linq OrderBy - Get Name By ID

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to Sort a List by it's names, but I don't know how to do it when i just have got a ID. Example:

```
public class CustomTask {

    int categoryid;
}

public class DataOption {
    int id;
    string name;
}

public void Sort() {

    List<DataOption> TheListContainingTheCategories = ...;

    // The List containing my CustomTasks
    List<CustomTask> listTempTasks = ...
    var listTasksSorted = listTempTasks.OrderBy(...).ToList();
}
```

Sorting the IDs is not really hard, but how do i do that when i want to sort it by the names?

Thanks for your help

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to match the CustomTask and DataOption by id, and sort by name? If so, have a look at the `Join` operator in Linq

Comment: You can only sort by properties that are member of your `CustomTask` class - because this class does not have any `name` property you cannot sort by that.

Comment: you need your class of `CustomTask` to include a property of `Name` to accomplish what you're asking..  otherwise you are only going to be able to sort by `categoryid`

Comment: you can order by something like `listTempTasks.OrderBy(ct => GetCustomTaskName(ct.id)`.

Comment: something like this: `.OrderBy(p => TheListContainingTheCategories.FirstOrDefault(q => q.id == p.categoryid)?.name)`

Comment: @Sem he is unable to do that.. without `name` being a property of CustomTask

Comment: @Alex what i posted as answer works without name member in custom task

Comment: @Sem's answer worked, thanks to everyone

Answer (score 1):

Guess the shortest way to do this is

```
var listTasksSorted = from ct in listTempTasks
                      join d in TheListContainingTheCategories on ct.categoryid equals d.id
                      orderby d.name
                      select new {ct, d};
```

then `listTasksSorted` looks like this

[image: linq result order by name]

So The list is ordered by Name and the id's are together and no need of extra functions or members

An Alternative would be

```
var listTasksSortedAlternative = TheListContainingTheCategories.Where(d => 
                                 listTempTasks.Any(ct => 
                                 d.id == ct.categoryid)).OrderBy(d => d.name);
```

Which would look like

[image: alternative linq]

Comment: Or just `select ct` if OP needs the DataOption only for sorting

Comment: @KooKiz yeah just took everything he could get because I dont know what he needs after sorting ;)

Comment: Hehehe... I totally forgot the ability of joining xD

Comment: @Alex Just for your because you forgot about join, i've added an alternative :P There OP could even use multiple sort with `ThenBy` in case Id's or names can be dupes

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void Sort() 
{
        List<DataOption> TheListContainingTheCategories = ...;
        Dictionary<int, string> lookup = TheListContainingTheCategories.ToDictionary(x => x.id, x => x.name);
        List<CustomTask> listTempTasks = new List<CustomTask>();
        var listTasksSorted = listTempTasks.OrderBy(c => lookup[c.categoryid]).ToList();
}
```

given that you want to sort by the matching

> DataOption.name when DataOption.id == CustomTask.categoryId